# Confused on How to Determine Block Size of a Cache

Tags: memory

I have some confusion on determining the block size of a cache. I read that to get the block size, you do 2^(block offset bits). However, if you're given a block offset and a byte offset, do you combine the total offset or just use those block offset bits?